# Could anyone recommend a good book about the basics of astrophysics?

Tags: black-hole, astrophysics

I am sorry if a similar question has been asked before. I look at other questions but was not entirely satisfied. So, I am a Psychology student who would like to know more about the basics of astrophysics. Could anyone recommend a good book about this. Also, I am particularly interested in black holes, so introductory literature on that is welcome too.

Comment: What's your background?  How much college-level math have you had?

Comment: Good question! I had a decent amount of math during highschool but was not very good at it. I barely had any math in college.

Comment: based on that I'd recommend a survey type book like the one suggested by astrosnapper.

Answer (score 2):

Answers to these sort of questions tend to be opinion-based which is frowned upon, but Neil DeGrasse Tyson's recent book *Astrophysics for People in a Hurry* has had very positive reviews. Injecting some facts, it has apparently spent a year on the New York Times bestseller lists and has sold over a million copies. It could be a good place to get you started before starting on a e.g. introductory college/university textbook.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right, book recommendations are mostly opinion-based, still I think people here have a lot of knowlegde and can provide me with input. So thanks for your recommendation. Much appreciated.

Comment: No, I agree that there will be plenty of people looking to get started or to go further and we ought to encourage that so more people can experience the wonder of astronomy. A curated selection of a couple of titles at a few levels of experience could be a wiki entry maybe. Question for meta?

Comment: Mm, I am somewhat new to stackexchange, so do not know much about meta but your idea sounds like a good one to me!

Answer (score 2):

I personally like [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805304029) by Caroll & Ostlie. It covers different areas of astrophysics, which are [listed here](http://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/toc/ecip0613/2006015391.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check it out!

Comment: Caroll & Ostlie was my first thought too. However, it assumes at least a fair bit of physics knowledge, it is very much a textbook rather than a popular introduction.

Comment: Okay, well I have to admit that do not know much about the basics of physics unfortunately, so that will make it harder to read I guess.